# Synchronizing folders between 2 windows servers

Tags: windows, synchronization

I have 2 windows servers. One has windows server 2003 and the other one has windows server 2008. I have multiple folders which content needs to be synchronized. What are the solutions for this? The folders needs to be synced directly between the servers so third party host like dropbox isn't an option.

Comment: This is off-topic, its a shopping/design/architecture question.

Comment: @BrentPabst Design and architecture questions are actually on-topic.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Funny, every single recommendation based question for design and architecture I have seen has been closed simply because it calls for opinions on which platforms to use.  I could have easily said rsync as opposed to DFS below or heck even xcopy, all would be valid.

Comment: @BrentPabst  No they wouldn't have been.  DFS actually replicates.  xcopy does not, and rsync is a Linux tool.  Having said that, while it may be on topic, it's also a lousy question because 5 seconds on the search, or Google would have given him the same answer... but that makes it a lousy on-topic question.  There's not a whole lot of subjectivity left when the OS comes with exactly one replication tool designed for the exact job asked in the question.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Yea, I can see what you mean.  BTW you can use rsync on Windows, been there and done that, it does work pretty well btw.  It is probably about the same amount of pain and suffering as setting up DFS properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for DFS replication.

Comment: Built into the operating-system!